# How does one set the favicon to a gif in Vue3 crated via the Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js

How does one set the favicon to a gif in Vue3 crated via the Vue CLI? I can't find it anywhere in the docs!

I tried adding a favicon.ico to the src/assets directory but nope, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to put your favicon in the public folder